# VB runtime error 53 file not found

Tags: vba, excel

I have macro running in an Excel sheet. However am getting the error file not found but the files are in the specified directory. See the below code and not sure what we are missing. The error happens when calling SQLLDR .

```
        Shell ("SQLLDR USERID= srvmacro/srvmacroswazi@pn81.world CONTROL=" & outfile & " LOG=" & outfile & ".LOG")
        'Shell ("SQLLDR USERID= srvmacro/srvmacroswazi@pn81.world CONTROL=" & outfile & " LOG=" & outfile & ".LOG")
        MsgBox " Done all   "
    End If
    'Unload UserForm1
End Sub
```

Comment: what is the value of `outfile`?

Comment: outfile = InputBox("Name of file to upload", "Upload to Oracle", "C:\UPLOAD\INTREVERSE.CTL")

Answer (score 0):

Most likely is that you have a space (or other special character in your outfile variable

try the following to see what you are actually trying to execute...

```
msgbox "SQLLDR USERID=srvmacro/srvmacroswazi@pn81.world CONTROL=" & outfile & ", LOG=" & outfile & ".LOG"
```

It should probably be more like: -

```
shell ("SQLLDR USERID=srvmacro/srvmacroswazi@pn81.world CONTROL=""" & outfile & """, LOG=""" & outfile & ".LOG""")
```

*Note the escaped quotes and you are also missing a comma between the keywords*

Comment: the INTREVERSE.CTL file is automatically created but the INTREVERSE.CTL.LOG file is not created, what could be the reason?

Comment: Can you paste your updated code in, If you have added the missing comma, then I would have to test it